# nginx rewrite - proxy if file not exists

Tags: nginx, proxy, url-rewriting

I have a local directory (uploads) and an **S3** bucket setup.
when the user is uploading an image the file is stored on the local directory: `/uploads/member_id/image_name`
and after 30 minutes the system is uploading the files to **S3** with the same path: `s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/member_id/image_name;`

I have setup this rewrite rule on my nginx server but it's not working.
this rule should check if the file is exists locally, and if not, open a proxy to **S3**..

Any idea how to fix it?

```
location /uploads/
{
    rewrite  ^/uploads/(.*)/([A-Za-z0-9\._]*)$ /uploads/$1/$2?imgname=$2&member=$1;
    try_files $uri @fallback;
}

location @fallback
{
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass $scheme://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/$arg_member/$arg_imgname;
    proxy_set_header Host s3.amazonaws.com;
}
```

Comment: did you set root definition so that nginx knows where to search for the file locally?

Comment: yes, the root is set and if I remove the location /uploads/ I can see the file locally.

Comment: try to add error_log directive into fallback location and put the details here please. The most important things to proxying files from S3 is *proxy_pass* and *resolver* but you can tune it up a bit like here: https://coderwall.com/p/rlguog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should adjust your `location` block to use a combination of a `rewrite` and a `proxy_pass` directive, such that each request is rewritten dynamically.  As your configuration stands, the variables don't appear to be resolved on a per-request basis - according to [Nginx's documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass), only the server name, port, and URI can be specified by variables.

What you need is something akin to this, rewriting the URI and definitively specifying a proxy:

```
location @fallback 
{
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    rewrite ^.*$ /bucket/$arg_member/$arg_imgname break;
    proxy_pass http://s3.amazonaws.com;
    proxy_set_header Host s3.amazonaws.com;
}
```

and to satisfy your switchable scheme (HTTP and HTTPS), the best option is likely to have two separate server blocks, with two different `@fallback` locations - one for HTTP and the other for HTTPS.  The `proxy_pass` location cannot resolve `$scheme` in this context.  Details are somewhat sketchy on what is supported (and why), but [Nginx's documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) is all we have to go on.